# How to get file type if file don't have extension

Tags: android

I want to know what is the file type, means it is image or not . but problem is in android 4.4.4 we don't have file extension , so How we know uploading file is image or not.

Comment: file stored locally ?

Comment: Of course there are file extensions under Android. But they are no guarantee. You could try to open a file by BitmapFactory to see if it is an image.

Comment: I just want to find the extension of file. don't want to open the File

Comment: Yes if we get a file with out any format/extension like just remove the extension of any file then try to find its extension.